# How can I create alternate colored rows with dynamically loaded data?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am creating a list of locations, and I need each location to have a different background color. The list is loaded dynamically from our SQL Server DB and it's built using Bootstrap Rows. How can I get alternating colors?

I've tried giving the rows an "nth-child" style, but because each row generates as one, it treats it as the first row no matter how many get generated. I've even tried to create a table, but it doesn't format or style properly.

[image]

The code that generates the list in the above image can be found below:

```
 @foreach (var hospital in Model)
    {
        <button class="top50accordion">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => hospital.StatesAbre[hospital.State])</button>
        <div class="panel">
            @foreach (var subhospital in hospital.NameCityCenterId)
            {
                string[] hosp = @subhospital.Split('+');
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6" style="margin: 5px 0;"><a href="~/ResearchCenter?id=@hosp[2]&alias=@hosp[0]" style="color:#0A5D66;font-weight:bold;" target="_blank">@hosp[0]</a></div>
                    <div class="text-right col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-5" style="margin: 5px 0;">@hosp[1]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

            }

        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

nth child should work using .panel .row as the selector.

```css
.panel .row:nth-child(even){
 background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="row">a</div>
  <div class="row">b</div>
  <div class="row">c</div>
  <div class="row">d</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="row">a</div>
  <div class="row">b</div>
  <div class="row">c</div>
  <div class="row">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Then, changing it from (even) to (odd), it just added the BG color to every row.

It still treats every row as an odd row

Comment: So you want every single line have a different color of a rainbow dynamically generated??

Comment: No. It should alternate between gray and white

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this...

```
.panel .row:nth-child(even){
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.panel .row:hover{
 background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: That adds a hover effect and works, but that doesn't make the rows alternating colors

Comment: Probably another Style is interfering on your CSS. try to remove this: style="color:#0A5D66; from your div
<div class="col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6" style="margin: 5px 0;"><a href="~/ResearchCenter?id=@hosp[2]&alias=@hosp[0]" style="color:#0A5D66;font-weight:bold;" target="_blank">@hosp[0]</a></div>

Comment: That style is the font color. When the list generates, it's treating every row as an odd number row. That's what I can't solve for it seems